# span class locator is not visible/clickable - selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is the HTML for span:

```
<td class="header-logout-btn">
 <a href="logout.htm" class="btn switch-btn">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Home</span>
 </a>
</td>
```

Tried with:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("HOME"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class="header-logout-btn"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span"));
driver.findElement(By.className("hidden-xs"));
```

Comment: As the class name itself mentions, it is hidden and so we cant interact with it. We need to make it visible by mouse hovering to parent element before

Comment: Try with - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Home')]"))

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution :

Xpath=  `//*[contains(text(),'Home')]`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the logout button will be submenu or it will be visible only if you click or mouse over on main menu usually the main menu is profile icon. I assume this logout button visible only after clicking on main/profile button. This may be the reason the button is hidden or not clickable.  The solutions are given below.
1. First click or mouse over on main/profile menu then click on logout button.
2. Still you want to click on hidden button. You may be try with JavaScript executor as given below.

```
Webelement eleLogout=driver.find element(By.class name("switch-btn"));
JavaScriptExecutor js=(JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments [0].click()",eleLogout);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the link.

Use selectors like:

xpath:
  `//a[contains(@href, 'logout')]` or
  `//*[@class='header-logout-btn']/a[contains(@href, 'logout')]`

css:
`a[href*=logout]` or
`.header-logout-btn a[href*=logout]`